# Raise a notification in Jenkins Freestyle Project

Tags: jenkins, notifications

I have a scenario where I call an external API through powershell, as part of the build steps.

The requirement is to raise a notification in a Jenkins freestyle project. E.g. if the API replies with an error, I need to raise a warning, which will subsequently trigger a Teams notification.

Is it possible to train a notification in a Jenkins freestyle project?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build's failure/unstable state can be be notified to Teams.
When the API call returns an error, it needs to make the build state as failed/unstable.

When the API call returns an error, log an error/warning to the console log. This error/warning can be detected using [Log Parser](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/) and it can mark the build as failed/unstable. The build's failure/unstable state is then automatically notified to Teams.